# Derivative of $g(x)=(f(x))(x)$?

Tags: analysis

> Let $E,F$ Banach spaces, $U$ an open set, $0\in U$. Let $f:U\to L(E,F)$ of class $C^1$ in $U$, and let $g(x)=(f(x))(x)$, for all $x\in U$. 
>   Problem have two parts:

**a)** Show $g$ is of class $C^1$ and compute its derivative.

**b)** Show if $f(0)\in Isom(E,F)$ then there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $0\in E$ and other 'hood $W$ of $0\in F$ such that $g$ is a diffeomorphism of class $C^1$ from $V$ to $W$. $Isom $ means Isometry.

Comment: What does $L(E,F)$ mean -- the space of linear maps $E\to F$?

Comment: Consider $g(x+h) - g(x) = f(x+h)(x+h) - f(x+h)(x) + f(x+h)(x) - f(x)x$. Use the fact, that $f$ is $C^1$. (Sorry, I have split the terms in a wrong way first).

Comment: @HenningMakholm: only continuous linear maps would make sense. Wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For a)**

For $x+h\in U$ and $h\to 0$ we have
$$\begin{align}
g(x+h) - g(x) 
&= f(x+h)(x+h) - f(x+h)(x) + f(x+h)(x) - f(x)(x) \\
&= f(x)(h) + \mathcal O(\|h\|^2) + f'(x)(h)(x) + \mathcal o(\|h\|).
\end{align}$$
Thus, we obtain $g'(x)(h) = f(x)(h) + f'(x)(h)(x)$.

**For b)**
From
$$ g'(0)(h) = f(0)(h) + f'(0)(h)(0) = f(0)(h)$$
follows $g'(0) = f(0)$. Thus, by inverse function theorem, $g$ is locally a $C^1$ diffeomorphism.

Comment: Very nice and detailed!! Thanks you.